# Apple member center login error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I am login to apple and try to access my certificates through Member Center tab I am getting this error
You’ve already agreed to the Apple Developer Agreement.
And Also the http link converted into
https://developer.apple.com/register/error/
Can any one help me on it?

Comment: Maybe you could get help here on SO, but I think you should post this on the Apple Developer forums. You likely will get more help there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question and Stack Overflow is not an Apple FAQ or customer support.

Comment: I am also suffering from same problem...have you got the solution

Comment: I originally had the same problem when I used a non-Apple browser. Try Safari.  :(

Comment: and yet again apple amazes me with their luck of care for users when they throw at you this absolutely idiotic "You’ve already agreed to the Apple Developer Agreement" instead of telling you to verify email.

Comment: @nhgriff - FYI it was the only place where I could find the explanation to this apple stupidity

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

My problem was that I haven't got confirm e-mail from Apple. I fixed this on apple ID page.

Try to login with your Apple ID on https://appleid.apple.com/

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you haven't verified your email address with Apple.

Go to https://appleid.apple.com/ and log in then sent another verification email.

Better explanation here https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/how-to-fix-youve-already-agreed-to-the-apple-developer-agreement/

Answer (score 0):

Just go to : https://appleid.apple.com/account/verify/email and click on 
"Send Verification Email"

and verify you developer email.

[image]